# Vectors in functions

Tags: c++, vector

I have these code lines in my .cpp file:

```
    void Student::operator+=(const Subject &a){
        vector<Subject> v;
        v.push_back(a);
    }
```

and I have this operator overloaded:

```
    ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, Student &a){
        vector<Subject>v;
        /*for (auto& a:v){
            output<<a<<endl;
        }
        */
        cout<<v.size()<<endl;
        return output;
    }
```

As It seems ,when Im trying to print the elements of the vector it shows that its empty.
The v.size() of it is 0.

Although I have commented out another way of showing the elements,it doesnt work as well.
I dont know why my vector loses its size when its used in functions.
Any possible help?

Comment: _`void Student::operator+=(const Subject &a)`_ looks like a very serious design flaw of your `Student` class.

Comment: Think about when and where you define your vector variable**s** `v` (and yes, the plural ending is intentional)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mean should I include my vector inside the parameters of the operator overload?My brain is brunt out...

Comment: @LyprandosLiatsos The vector is declared (created) on the stack as a local variable. Meaning it's local to the function, and it doesn't exist outside the function. When the function enters it'll get created and when it exits it'll be destroyed, effectively doing nothing.

Comment: I mean that you should have *one* vector, as a member of the `Student` class. You should not define different vectors as local variables inside the functions. Please take some time to read more about scope (and life-time) in your text-books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector `vector<Subject> v;` is in each operator implementation function, and therefore is generated just locally in each function, and will be destroyed by its end.
Think about declaring this vector one time, as a private member of your `Student` class.

Comment: You are right and I deleted each vector declaration inside my functions.But I get this error :
student.cpp:146:9: error: ‘v’ was not declared in this scope
  146 |   cout<<v.size()<<endl;
My functions are all friend functions.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Right, `‘v’ was not declared in this scope` because it's not in the function, but you should declare it once as a member of the class, so both function will have access to it.

Comment: Figured out I had to a.v.size() in order to show stuff.Well thanks a lot for your help!